# How to update and redeploy Golem shiny app package (currently creates a new tar.gz, but none of the changes appear)

Tags: r, shiny, golem

I have a shiny app that I built using golem. The app is to be run locally on the user's computer, rather than on a shiny server. I deployed the package using the `03_deploy.R script` that is automatically created by golem, using `devtools::build()` to build a new tar.gz. However, when I make changes to the app and redeploy it (create a new tar.gz), none of my changes appear. I also tried updating the version in the DESCRIPTION file, but that doesn't work either. The changes do appear if I change the name of the package.

How can I redeploy it, with the changes, without having to change the name of the package every time I want to update it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that my problem was on the installation end, not the building/deploying end. I needed to uninstall the earlier version of the package (`remove.packages('mypackage')`) and then restart my RStudio session.